# JavaScript splitting a string error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to split this string

```
"http://localhost/webproject/products.html?product=Apple%20iPhone%206%20With%20FaceTime%20class="
```

to this

```
"Apple iphone 6 with Facetime"
```

but my code only splits it to

```
"Apple iphone 6 with Facetime class"
```

and when I'm trying to remove the class word and alert the string, it appears as empty. When I alert `split5` it appears as `NaN`

```
var url = window.location.href;
var split = url.split('=');
var split2 = split[1];
var split3 = split2.replace(/20/g,"");
var split4 = split3.replace(/%/g, " ");
var split5 = split4.count-5;
var split6 = split4.slice(0, split5);
alert(split6);
```

Comment: `split4.count`? You mean `split4.length`?

Comment: Save yourself some time: `var split2 = decodeURI(split[1]);`

Comment: Dammit I forgot thank you. I'm used to the Array List in c#.

Comment: If `product` and `class` are meant to be separate arguments, there should be a `&` between them that you can `.split()` on first.

Answer (score 1):

@Karim, what's going on is you're using replace and then counting the -5 over the location of those characters. That's why it is returning `NaN`.

Here is what you want:

```js
var url = 'http://localhost/webproject/products.html?product=Apple%20iPhone%206%20With%20FaceTime%20class=';
var split = url.split('=');
var split2 = split[1];
var split3 = split2.split('%20');
alert(split3.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string by '%20', remove the last value using `pop()` and then join the result:

```js
var url = "http://localhost/webproject/products.html?product=Apple%20iPhone%206%20With%20FaceTime%20class="

var split1 = url.split('=')[1]
var split2 = split1.split('%20')
split2.pop()
alert(split2.join(' '))
```

More info on [Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Answer (score 0):

You can done better way using `decodeURI()` method. Instead of `count` you have to use `length`.

`string` don't have `count` property that is why you are getting `NaN1.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var split = url.split('=');
var split2 = decodeURI(split[1]);
var split5 = split2.length-5;
var split6 = split2.substring(0, split5);
alert(split6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, as a shortcut, you can set the second argument of the string.slice method to a negative number to remove that many characters from the end of the string, eg -5 to slice off the last 5 characters.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice